# How to update a record using PHPActiveRecord and CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

Im breaking my head here. Hope you can see what's the error. I've installed PHPActiveRecord to CodeIgniter throught a spark and all works great except one thing. Let me show you some code.

This is my problematic controller.

Model **Article.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Article extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('category'),
        array('user')
    );

    public function updater($id, $new_info)
    {
            // look for the article
        $article = Article::find($id);

            // update modified fields
        $article->update_attributes($new_info);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is the part where it shows me an error. Relevant code in Controller **articles.php**

```
        // if validation went ok, we capture the form data.
        $new_info = array(
            'title'       => $this->input->post('title'),
            'text'        => $this->input->post('text'),
            'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
         );

        // send the $data to the model                          
        if(Article::updater($id, $new_info) == TRUE) {
            $this->toolbox->flasher(array('code' => '1', 'txt' => "Article was updated successfully."));
        } else {
            $this->toolbox->flasher(array('code' => '0', 'txt' => "Error. Article has not been updated."));
        }

        // send back to articles dashboard and flash proper message
        redirect('articles');
```

When i call Article::updater($id, $new_info), it display a big annoying error:

**Fatal error:** Call to a member function update_attributes() on a non-object

**The weirdest thing, is that i have a controller called categories.php and model Categoy.php** that has the same functionality (i copy pasted the categories functionality for the articles) and this time, doesn't work.

I have different functions inside model Article.php and all of them work fine, im struggling with that Article::updater part.

Does somebody know for a way to proper update a row? Im using as stated at docs in PHP AR site and it's giving me that error. Why it does say that is not an object? It's supposed to be an object when i do $article = Article::find($id).

Maybe im not seeing something really easy. Too many hours in front of computer.

Thanks amigos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function updater needs to be marked static, and it should handle the error condition when $id is bad.

```
public static function updater($id, $new_info)
{
        // look for the article
    $article = Article::find($id);
    if ($article === null)
        return false;

        // update modified fields
    $article->update_attributes($new_info);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks walrii but this still showing up Fatal error: Call to a member function update_attributes() on a non-object in Article.php on line 29 where line 29 is: $article->update_attributes($new_info);

Comment: What was $article initialized to on line 29.  I'm betting it is null or an int.  It needs to be an object to use the -> operator.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Maybe $article is not being initialized because maybe $id is getting lost somewhere. Let me try.

Comment: @Richard-MX If $id is invalid, I would expect $article to be set to null.  Then updater should return false instead of continuing.

Comment: WTF with me. I forgot to pass the $id. That's why the $article object was never getting initialized. Thanks for the tip walrii. Have a good night.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change:

```
public function updater($id, $new_info)
    {
            // look for the article
        $article = Article::find($id);
```

to:

```
public static function updater($id, $new_info)
    {
            // look for the article
        $article = Article::find($id);
```

Comment: Yes, i put it like this
 public static function updater($id, $new_info)
 {
  $article = Article::find($id);
  $article->update_attributes($new_info);
  return true;
 }

But still showing the error.

Comment: Change `$article = Article::find($id);` to `$article = self::find($id);`

Comment: Patrick, thanks for your help. As i said below to walrii, the $id wasn't passed to the updater() function. Now it's working :) Have a good night.